# JavaScript For Loop Double Equal

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding why using a double equals (or even a triple equals) in the conditional part of a for loop doesn't work. For example:

```
for (i = 1; i == 5; i++){
    console.log(i)
}
```

If I use `<=` instead it works and I don't understand.

Comment: It does "work" but it doesn't seem to do what you want. The loop only executes as long as the condition is `true`. `i == 5` is only `true` if `i` is `5`. Since `i` has an initial value of `1`, the condition will be `false` and the loop terminates immediately.

Comment: You should read it as "as long as `i` meets the condition, enter the loop". `i` starts with `1` and so it doesn't meed the condition `i == 5` and doesn't enter. However, it does meet the condition `i <= 5` because 1 is less than 5.

Comment: Oh Jesus. Thanks man. Brain fart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop works while the given condition `i <= 5` is fulfilled (if it returns false, `for` loop aborts).

In case of `i == 5`, condition returns `false` at the beginning (`i` equalls to `1`), so the `loop` doesn't even start.

Comment: It works **while** the condition is fulfilled, not **until**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. The condition only executes if true and since i = 1 the condition i == 5 is false. Thank you.